# Grabbing the text from .doc, .docx, and rtf files and displaying them into a text field (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, doc

I have a `Post` model:

```
  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                            :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                            :null => false
    t.integer  "comments_count",     :default => 0,     :null => false
    t.boolean  "published",          :default => false
    t.datetime "published_at"
    t.boolean  "draft",              :default => false
  end
```

And this is its form:

```
<%= form_for(@post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :draft %>
    <%= f.check_box :draft %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm looking for a way to grab the text from `.doc, .docx, and rtf` files and displaying them into the `content` text field (so the user doesn't have to open his file, copy, and paste the text into the form).

Any suggestions?

(Is there any gem, text editor, or jQuery plugin that accomplishes this?)?

**EDIT:**

Got stuck here:

**post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'docx'
  .
  .
  .  
  def read_docx
    d = Docx::Document.open(self.document)
    d.each_paragraph do |p|
      puts d
    end
  end
end
```

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
  .
  .
  .
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @post = @user.posts.new(params[:post])
    @doc_text = (no idea what to do here)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'post was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
  .
  .
  .
```

**posts/new.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(@post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, :value => @doc_text %>
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
```

**I already made Paperclip upload docx files**

I created a new field called `:document`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I just tried [docx](https://github.com/mportiz08/docx) gem and it works fine. You can get 2 examples on its github page. Sadly it does not work for doc files.

For them you can use this gem [here](https://github.com/dayflower/msworddoc-extractor). There is some example on the github page, but if you want to get the whole content of the doc file just do like this:

```
require 'msworddoc-extractor'

MSWordDoc::Extractor.load('sample.doc') do |doc|
  puts doc.whole_contents
end
```

There are other methods you can call for `doc`, like `document` or `header`. Again, check the github page.

For rtf you can go with this [gem](https://github.com/thechrisoshow/rtf) as well.

Now, to pass it inside the `content` is easy. Just definy how you will get the data from the files, like an external lib called on the controller:

```
@doc_text = Parser.doc("file.doc")
@docx_text = Parser.docx("file.docx")
@rtf_text = Parser.rtf("file.rtf")
```

Or just get the values directly or by any method you have in mind. To show it on view you just have to add `:value` option like this:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, :value => @doc_text %> 
#Where @doc_text is the data from file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry, I'm a beginner in this. Where exactly I have to put the code above? Controller (which action?) or Model or a function? (I only know where to put the code for the form in the view). I'm trying docx right now.

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want to achieve. You could implement it anywhere, but following the good patterns, if you want to load the files when the user access the form, I think the best you can do is to create an external lib inside the lib directory, include it on your controller and call the methods to load the files. But if it sounds hard for you, implement the methods inside the controller's model and call it inside the controller like I did.

Comment: And if you want to try out the gems I suggest you to open an `irb` in your terminal and play around there, since the examples are short and simple.

Comment: Sorry, ha is the first time I work with something like this. I got stuck halfway (not sure if I did it right). Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: If you want to display the text on the form when the user access it you have to create the method inside `new` not `create`. You should now call `Post.read_docx`inside `new`.